# Comunicação Cliente Servidor via protocolo SNMP

Tags: c#, dll, snmp

Estou tentando criar uma comunicação entre cliente e servidor via protocolo SNMP, e para começar, instalei o Visual Studio 2017 e baixei, via NuGet, a library Lextm.SharpSnmpLib. Procurei na internet um exemplo de código para que eu pudesse uma base.
Até chegar neste código:

```
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace SNMPGetStart
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V2,
                           new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 161),
                           new Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.OctetString("public"),
                           new List<Variable> { new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5")) },
                           60000);
            txtIP.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

está disparando uma exceção no arquivo `SharpSnmpLib.dll`

```
Exceção gerada: 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.ErrorException' em SharpSnmpLib.dll
Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento do tipo "Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.ErrorException" em SharpSnmpLib.dll
error in response
```

O que poderia ser?
Como posso achar um erro tão generalizado?

Comment: o repositório dessa biblioteca é esse: https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib ?
já tentou fazer um clone e procurar esse erro?

Comment: eu não sei, eu baixei a biblioteca via NuGet, vou verificar

Comment: Parece que é sim, só não sei a versão da biblioteca que ta desse link, aqui no meu projeto é 11.3.0